# How to access properties of uninitialized component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I can't figure out how to access properties of a component in Angular using Ionic Framework Tutorial template. It seems to be uninitialized, because I tried to print it out to the console. Here is the code in app.component.ts:

```
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  pages: Array<{title: string, badge: number, component: any}>;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public menu: MenuController,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    public authService: AuthService,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    private toastCtrl: ToastController
  ) {
   this.initializeApp();

   // set our app's pages
   this.pages = [
     { title: 'Series', badge: 0, component: SeriesDetailPage },
     { title: 'Borrow', badge: 0, component: BorrowViewPage },
     { title: 'Request', badge: 0, component: RequestViewPage },
     { title: 'Borrow List', badge: 0, component: BorrowListPage },
     { title: 'Request List', badge: 0, component: RequestListPage },
     { title: 'Setting', badge: 0, component: SettingPage }
   ];

   var borrowPage = this.pages.find(page => page.title === 'Borrow');
   console.log((borrowPage.component as BorrowViewPage).items); //Print undefined
   this.nav.setRoot(BorrowViewPage);
  }
  ...
  openPage(page) {
    // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
    this.menu.close();
    // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
```

Here is the code for BorrowViewPage component:

```
export class BorrowViewPage {
  public items: Borrow[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authService: AuthService, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.view(); //Make a HTTP call to initialize items array
  }
}
```

It seems that none of the components have its constructor called at this point. If so, is it possible to call the component constructor manually?

**ADDED:** What magical is that I don't know where the class instance even comes from. Here is where the app starts at app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    SettingPage,
    SeriesDetailPage,
    SeriesListPage,
    BorrowListPage,
    BorrowViewPage,
    RequestListPage,
    RequestViewPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    SettingPage,
    SeriesDetailPage,
    SeriesListPage,
    BorrowListPage,
    BorrowViewPage,
    RequestListPage,
    RequestViewPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    AuthService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

By setting the root page to any page you want in app.component.ts, the constructor of that component name get called. I think the constructor is called then?! Not sure. It works in the same way when I click on any of the buttons specified in app.html:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">

  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>MyApp</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
        <ng-container *ngIf="p.badge != 0">
            <span class="badge badge-assertive">{{p.badge}}</span>
        </ng-container>
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

How do I even retrieve that class instance in this case?

Comment: It's completely unclear from your code what its desired behavior is. Simplifying a bit, doing `{ component: SeriesDetailPage }` you'll get **class** into the property instead of **class instance** - which obviously is not what you need. However, no one except you have any idea about where to get that instance from because it depends solely on the rest of your code... Most obvious way would be to do smth like this: `{component: new SeriesDetailPage(...params...) }` - but considering constructor params suggesting DI it is very unlikely you want it like this.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea where that class instance comes from. This is mystery to me. It just work like that. I just don't know how. Let me post the code for app.module.cs. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my answer here as I realized I just jumped into conclusion (that because you have async call the data is not yet available and hence result is 'undefined').

Now as I looked closer I realize that what you are trying to do (access child's component (BorrowViewPage) data/property from parent scope (MyApp)) is not conventional and is not how Angular wants you to do it: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction

I think in your use case you should consider this interaction model:https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Rationale here is that in your case both components (MyApp and BorrowViewPage) require to access same data which ideally should be available at a "foundation" or "shared" service.

Service should be initialized and imported/injected into each of the components and this way you are getting cleaner design:

[image]

It is also a better practice to move your http calls to a provider and have components call / subscribe to them. So I think you can get cleaner implementation this way.

If you have a reason why you still want to achieve something with your current approach and that the canonical approach (shared service) is not suitable - please share those reasons.

Comment: I tried adding the items2 to BorrowViewPage. And print that out to the console in the constructor of MyApp, but it is still undefined.

Comment: Hmm i will create stackblitz and check it out, then will update answer

Comment: @IceDrake updated the answer - I think you should get out of the woods by adopting angular way of doing things;) looking at your case I don't know why would you want to access a property of another class the way you wanted.

Comment: I am new to Ionic, Angular, and Typescript. After going through the various tutorials and reading a few poorly written books on Ionic Framework, I am starting to wonder how to structure my code for this app I am making, because I am running into more of this type of access issues. And your answer came along and pointed me to the right way. What a great timing! Thanks!