# pass data to sidemenu Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a login with fb, and upon confirming, redirects to the main page, however I would like to pass the data to the App.html, because my sideMenu is in it. But I can not find way to pass data to app.component.ts
Can anyone give me an idea of ​​how I get data for the side menu?

Comment: You need to have a shared provider (service) that app, any page or component can import/inject and access n xchange data. See angular.io docs for component interaction using shared service

Comment: See in this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53200559/4005366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) plugin by ionic

in your `app.component.ts` file either create a function or put the code below inside the platform ready to listen for any published events

```
  events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
    // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
    console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
  });
```

in your `login.ts` file after successfully login publish data using the code below

```
this.events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
```

for more info please read the [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) plugin

Comment: Thanks for replying, I believe I have succeeded, but I do not know how to receive the username in the html. but in console.log I was able to see the data being passed.

Comment: app.component.ts:   this.createUser(events);

createUser(events) {
    events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
      // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
      console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
     console.log(user);
    });

   
  }



in my console I see that I received the value of User

Comment: so you declare global variable in your `app.component.ts`

    variable:any;

   events.subscribe('user:created',(user,time)=>{

  this.variable = user;

});

then you can get the user in html by using {{ variable }}

Comment: Thanks, I get almost everything, but in html when I insert {{user}} it returns in html [Object, Object]

Comment: what value does user contains? user is an object that why it prints `[Object, Object]`